# Qna maker returns answers with high confidence scores for values like "abcd" which is not in KB, for which azure search also returns null

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

user query:

```
{
"question": "abcd",
"top": 20
}
```

response from qna maker:

```
{
"questions": [
"How do I add my account?",
],
"answer": "In portal, login and add account",
"score": 81.11
}
```

for the same query, azure search to which this qna app is linked doesn't return any answer.
1. If there are no records returned from azure search, how is qna maker portal displaying the answer? 
2. Is Qna performing some spell check and mapping "abcd" as "add" in the above query?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the some of the debugging options.

To check correct search tier hook to QnA Maker app service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure#configure-qna-maker-to-use-different-cognitive-search-resource

To restore existing indexes per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/upgrade-qnamaker-service#upgrade-azure-search-service

The Bot Framework Emulator is a cross-platform desktop application that allows users to connect-to and test their local or remote bot, allowing inspection of the conversation history and internal bot state built using the Bot Framework SDK. It can be used to test interactions (text and speech), inspect payloads, generate, save, and load conversation transcripts, and generally promotes fast iteration of bot development.

The emulator also provides an “attach to live conversation” diagnostic experience for any Bot Framework supported first and third-party channels: Direct Line, Direct Line Speech, Microsoft Teams, Cortana, Slack, Facebook Messenger, etc.